# What is the order of growth of the worst case running time of the following code fragment as a function of N?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i = i*2)
    for (int j = 1; j <= N; j = j*2)
        for (int k = 1; k <= j; k++)
            sum++;
```

According to the solution it is NlogN. However, I thought it would be just logN. The `i` for loop iterates logN times because i doubles with each iteration. the `j` for loop is the same as the `i` for loop so it iterates logN times as well. Finally, the `k` for loop, because it is set to be less than or equal to `j`, it will iterate the same number of times `j` does and thus, we have another logN iterations. Multiplying the three together we get logN * logN * logN total iterations or (logN)^3 for the complexity. Why is my thought process incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sum++;
```

That's obviously O(1)

```
for (int k = 1; k <= j; k++)
    sum++;
```

The loops run `j` times, so that's `O(j)`

```
for (int j = 1; j <= N; j = j*2)
    for (int k = 1; k <= j; k++)
        sum++;
```

So this gets tricky. We know the inner loop is `O(j)` but `j` is changing in the outer loop. You said:

> Finally, the k for loop, because it is set to be less than or equal to j, it will iterate the same number of times j does

No. The `j` loop is counting by doubles. But the inner loop is counting by increments. They won't go the same number of iterations.

Since each inner loop runs in O(j) time, we simply need to sum j for each time in the loop. `j` doubles each time so that gives us:

```
1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ... + n
```

This sequence ends up being slightly less then 2n. (Why is left as an excersize to the reader.) Thus its `O(n)`

```
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i = i*2)
    for (int j = 1; j <= N; j = j*2)
        for (int k = 1; k <= j; k++)
            sum++;
```

The outer loop doesn't interact with the inner loops, and runs `log(N)` times giving us `O(N log N)`

Comment: How did you know right off the bat that summing the run times of each of the loops gives `1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ... + n`? Is it because you know from experience or is there a quick method that can figure this out?

Comment: @JustinLiang, the inner loop runs `j` times. `j` is 1, the first time, 2 the second time, 4 the third time, etc. I'm just following the logic of the program.

Comment: Right, but isn't the j loop running logN times? Same goes with the i loop. So we should have N log^2(N)?

Comment: @JustinLiang, The problem is the `k` loop. In some case it runs once, and in other cases is runs `N` times. It comes out to running an average of O(N / log N) times. So you can't get away which just multiplying the `N` into it. You have to take into account that `j` is changing.

Answer (score 0):

Using Sigma notation, you may end up with the exact formula, methodically:

[image]